# Do HTML elements load even if they are not attached to DOM? What about backbone views?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

If I create an image tag without actually adding it to DOM and add source to it does it still get the image and load it. I mean when I attach it to DOM do I immediately see the image without any delay?

More specifically, I'm working with backbone currently. So if I create a bunch of backbone view's and store them in an array, each holding individual image, do those images render even if I don't attach it to DOM? And when I do attach one those views to DOM. Do I immediately see the images without any delay?

```
this.$el.append(view.render().el); // where view object was created before and stored in an array
```

Is this a good prefetching strategy and what about the memory constraints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's a frequent (and not very good) scheme for background image loading : you add the src to an Image element but don't add it to the DOM. The browser loads it just as if it was in the DOM.

When you add the images to the DOM after they have been loaded, they're immediately rendered.

Comment: Because browsers act too much like if they were added to the DOM and display a spinner cursor which makes the user think he should wait.

Comment: I've been using that async loading for a canvas library and never noticed a loading cursor.

Comment: @dystroy Ahh okay, I wasn't sure if there way another reason. At the same time, it's kind of useful =/ It's nice to have images ready before you use them. Does putting them directly in the DOM as `<img src="whatever" />` change anything about the spinner being there?

Comment: @ian What I do is using XmlHttpRequest. After all, the goal isn't really to have image elements ready but to ensure the images are in the cache.

Comment: @dystroy Ahh yes, that's a better way to say it. And I never thought of using AJAX. Is there any benefit to putting them directly in the DOM (as hidden)? Or does that still show the spinner cursor? I'm sure I could test, I just thought I'd see if you knew

Answer (score 0):

Even if you don't add the image element to the DOM tree, it's still created using the `document` object, so it belongs to that document. You simply can't create elements that exist independently of a document, so and as soon as the element exists the browser will request the image.

However, in the case of the view, it would depend on when you actually create the elements. If the `render` method creates the image element, it won't exist until right before you use it.